# insert query using foreach loop receiving Uncaught Error: Call to a member function execute() on boolean

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert multiple rows at once to my db, I posted a question here the other day [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37976978/loop-through-result-set-before-inserting-data-into-db?noredirect=1#comment63400846_37976978). Regarding my insert query only insert one row into the db, even if it was necessary for a 2 or more rows of data to be inserted into the DB. Due to the fact this insert query is inserting shopping cart data i am unaware of the number of items a user may insert into the db.

After spending a few days researching i found the method i am now using may be the best way to resolve the issue, this is my first time using a foreach loop, and creating a insert query this way, I am receiving the follow error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function execute() on boolean

Which i am aware means my prepare statement failed, but i was hoping someone could explain or demonstrate where i have gone wrong, as i am trying to learn from my mistakes. I am not sure if it is the way i have created my query or even the way i have executed it.

**Code**

```
$_query = "INSERT INTO ord_dets(Order_ID,custmer_ip,Resturant_ID,Resturant_name,City_name,
        Product_Id,Product_Name,Product_Price,item_sub) 
VALUES ";
        $_query_parts  = array();
        for($x=0;$x<count($OI); $x++){
        $_query_parts  = "('" . $OI[$x] . "', '" . $ip[$x] . "','" . $_SESSION['rest_id'][$x] . "','" . $rest_name[$x] . "',
            '" . $City_name[$x] . "','" . $Product_Id[$x] . "','" . $product_name[$x] . "','" . $prod_price[$x] . "','" . $item_sub[$x] . "')";
        }
       $query_run = $dbc->prepare($_query);
       echo $_query;

        if (!$query_run->execute()) {
            $insertError = "There was an error inserting data: " . $query_run->error;
      print "affected rows:" . $query_run->affected_rows; //how many records affected?         

    }
  }
```

Comment: The result is a boolean (`false`) because the query is failing.  You need to check for errors before continuing, never assume that a database operation was successful.  (Note:  The query fails because it's incomplete, resulting in a syntax error.  You forgot everything after the `VALUES` keyword.  You *do* build a horribly SQL-injectable string that you may have *meant* to use.  But don't do that.  Because it's horribly SQL-injectable.  Use query parameters.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysqli\_fetch\_array()/mysqli\_fetch\_assoc()/mysqli\_fetch\_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource or mysqli\_result, boolean given](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysqli-fetch-array-mysqli-fetch-assoc-mysqli-fetch-row-expects-parameter-1)

Comment: @David i had values, but the post on here which i am following suggested taking them out, Oh and i am aware of the sql injections. I am one to make sure everything working then go back on myself and tidy up

Comment: I don't know what suggestion you're referring to, but attempting to execute an invalid SQL statement clearly isn't going to work.  It seems highly likely that you misunderstood or misinterpreted that suggestion.  A SQL query has to be complete and syntactically valid in order for it to execute.  Databases can't read your mind.

Comment: I answered your question

Comment: @maxpovver thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL is generated incorrectly:
`INSERT INTO ord_dets(Order_ID,custmer_ip,Resturant_ID,Resturant_name,City_name,
        Product_Id,Product_Name,Product_Price,item_sub) 
VALUES (...,...,....)(...,...,....)(...,...,....)(...,...,....)(...,...,....)`

This is how it looks like. Fix it ad there will be no error

Solution here is to add commas betweeen values:
`VALUES (...,...,....),(...,...,....),(...,...,....),(...,...,....),(...,...,....)`

**UPD**: Actually I can't see where you add `$query_parts` to your query string

**UPD2**: this is how it should look to avoid sql injections:

```
$_query = "INSERT INTO ord_dets(Order_ID,custmer_ip,Resturant_ID,Resturant_name,City_name, Product_Id,Product_Name,Product_Price,item_sub) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
$stmt = $dbc->prepare($_query);

for($x=0;$x<count($OI); $x++){
    if (!$query_run->execute([$OI[$x] , $ip[$x], $_SESSION['rest_id'][$x] ,
          $rest_name[$x] , $City_name[$x] , $Product_Id[$x] ,
          $product_name[$x] , $prod_price[$x] ,$item_sub[$x]])) )
    {
        insertError = "There was an error inserting data: " . $query_run->error; 
          print "affected rows:" . $query_run->affected_rows;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer, i had "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"; before, but the post i am following suggests to take them out, do i put the question marks back and then keep the rest of the query as it is?

Comment: in that case you would have to run that query for every part of data

Comment: @user6456767 I added correct code(can't check it now)

Answer (score 0):

change it like this to separated it with coma.

```
$_query = "INSERT INTO ord_dets(Order_ID,custmer_ip,Resturant_ID,Resturant_name,City_name,
        Product_Id,Product_Name,Product_Price,item_sub) 
VALUES ";
        $_query_parts  = array();
        $sep ="";
        for($x=0;$x<count($OI); $x++){
        $_query_parts  = "$sep('" . $OI[$x] . "', '" . $ip[$x] . "','" . $_SESSION['rest_id'][$x] . "','" . $rest_name[$x] . "',
            '" . $City_name[$x] . "','" . $Product_Id[$x] . "','" . $product_name[$x] . "','" . $prod_price[$x] . "','" . $item_sub[$x] . "')";
        $sep=",";
        }
      $query_run = $dbc->prepare($_query);
       echo $_query;

        if (!$query_run->execute()) {
            $insertError = "There was an error inserting data: " . $query_run->error;
      print "affected rows:" . $query_run->affected_rows; //how many records affected?         

    }
  }
```

Comment: @user6456767 - can you please post the output from the **echo $_query;** statement, so than i can see what i am doin wrong

Comment: Hi only just seen this , i will post give me 2 minutes

Comment: INSERT INTO ord_dets(Order_ID,custmer_ip,Resturant_ID,Resturant_name,City_name, Product_Id,Product_Name,Product_Price,item_sub) VALUES. The above answer suggests have no value i.e question marks is the issue, but even that didn't work